# How to know my app is uninstalled from the device...?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app installed in many devices.

If app is uninstalled from any of the device I need an indication.

How to achieve this.

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: where you have to get indication ? in that device or any external device which controls/communicates with all your devices ? Please ask question clearly.

Comment: You mean you want any alert or toast message that say this your application is uninstalled. right ?

Comment: If it is like that then you already got it while uninstalling it from the device.

Comment: he wants to know when a user uninstalls his app from their device

Comment: Android Default behaviour is autometicaly notify user that the xyz app is uninstalled from your device.

Comment: @Yugandhar Babu I want indication to my server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to detect Android app uninstall?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209730/is-it-possible-to-detect-android-app-uninstall)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My proposal will be the following. You can intercept the intent for your application uninstall. Simply put the following code in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".UninstallIntentActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="package" android:pathPattern="com.testpack.yourapp" />
        </intent-filter>



    </activity>

</application>
```

After this you can somehow process that your application is going to be deleted (for instance, send you a email), and call the package manager uninstaller.

Comment: Do I need in add this into my app...?

Comment: My main activity is different. If I place this code my launcher activity will not launch when app started...!

Comment: Yep, of coarse you should modify the code. Here I've showed just permissions that you need and intent-filter.

Comment: Hi @Yury I want to send a mail to specific mail id wen user click on uninstall button.. Can u pls help me out..

Comment: I just tested this in Android 7.1.1 and it didn't work.

Comment: These permissions are only granted to system apps

Answer (score 1):

You cannot tell when someone uninstalls your app unless you keep track on the statistics in android market. And unless you have only a few installs, that may prove difficult

Comment: Then there's no way to do it.

Comment: I am in search of programmatic approach for the same task.

Comment: you CANNOT know when a device uninstalls your app programatically lol

Comment: its not lol..!! It is done already by McAfee, NQ and many others.

Comment: @BillGary its also done by UC Browser. It opens a webpage when app is uninstalled. I don't know what made you lol.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was creating a schedule job by sending an empty message to the device via GCM/FCM, if the response is "NotRegistered" from GCM/FCM then I know that the app has been removed from the device.

I do this "detection" once a day for reporting to show how many devices are still having my app installed.