# Android - How to perform any action while uninstalling my application?

Tags: android, android-calendar

My application will create Events in calendar. I need to remove all Events created by my application when user uninstalls my app. I have all Event id's stored. I need to remove all Events created based on these Event id's. How, can I achieve this. Please help.

Comment: AFAIK, you don't get your own app's uninstall event, still [you can give this a try](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22061900/1777090)

Comment: Please check this answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686673/how-to-know-my-app-is-uninstalled-from-the-device