# How to delete application directory while uninstalling android application

Tags: android

I am creating an application, whose directory is getting created on sdcard `("/mnt/sdcard/testzapp")`

I want when user `uninstall application` the directory is also deleted.
How can I do  this?

Comment: see this first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209730/is-it-possible-to-detect-android-app-uninstall

Answer (score 8, accepted):

unfortunately - the answer is: you can't!.

there is indeed broadcast you can listen to when application uninstall - but your app won't get any broadcast for it own uninstall.

what you can do:

instead of creating folder on external storage (sdcard..)   you can create your folder in the directory of your application with `Context.getFilesDir()`.  this path is internally for your application, and uninstall of your application will delete this folder also.

Answer (score 2):

May this help you:

**Only way to do that is If you use `getExternalCacheDir()`, then only folders auto deleted when uninstalling the application...**  **Refer this link:** [Click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#ExternalCache)

**OR:**

**Save it in your Applications Private Folder `(/data/data/yourappPackege)`. This folder will be removed when uninstalling the App.

You can get your private Folder with the Method `getFilesDir()` Other files can not be removed because your App does not "know" when it is being removed.**