# Handle Android Uninstall Event

Tags: android, events, uninstallation

Is it possible to catch an uninstall event?

Basically whenever a user uninstalls my app I would like to fire off a web intent showing a simple form asking why they chose to uninstall. I've seen a number of apps do this.

I'm not trying to prevent the uninstall in any way, rather just fire a browser intent when uninstall is complete to gather potential feedback from users leaving the app.

Whats the best way to go about implementing something like this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209730/is-it-possible-to-detect-android-app-uninstall

Answer (score 1):

NO! you cannot do that!

That's for obvious security reasons. If the user wants to uninstall an app, having said app interfere with it is not very safe.

Comment: Sorry - I'm not trying to prevent the user from uninstalling. Just when uninstall is complete I would like to fire a browser intent thats all.

Comment: I'm not saying you are trying to do and I'm not trying to stop you from doing. I'm just explaining  why one of the design decisions for the platform is to not allow it.

Comment: Thanks. But I've seen an app do this, will post its name once I recall it. Assuming they used some sort of a workaround a hack for this.