# Android uninstall notification

Tags: android

Is there any way to send notification when user uninstall app. If user uninstall the app the app owner should get the notification that the following user has been uninstalled the appp. Is it possible?

Comment: No. It's not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to detect Android app uninstall?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209730/is-it-possible-to-detect-android-app-uninstall)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible from app itself (barring case if there  other apps from same author which can check)
But I think there is usable but complex workaround.
App can register for push notifications (either via GCM or FCM). Server side part of part should store app token for this purpose.
If, after some time, server side part send push and get NotRegistered instead (see https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#error_codes ) this mean app was uninstalled.

edit:
it's possible using hacky way  from native code, per Roland's answer in [Is it possible to detect Android app uninstall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209730/is-it-possible-to-detect-android-app-uninstall)

> The method is based on the fact that the first thing android does when uninstalling your app is deleting your data file. So you could use a file watcher to detect the deletion. Also you need to write this in native code. If you write your code in java, your app will be uninstalled before it could execute any code. please see this demo : https://github.com/sevenler/Uninstall_Statics

Answer (score 0):

Actually answer is no, but you can use one hack way to find out currently app is available in user device or uninstalled.

Registered your app with GCM,and send daily one notification to user, in which day user did not receive notification then you can assume app is uninstall.

I don't know this way is good or not, just i explain may be you can achieve your requirement !

Comment: If your going to attempt this, use a silent non-displayable message. Daily notifications shown to the user will increase your uninstall rate.