# How do we know whether a user has installed or uninstalled the app?

Tags: android, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, uninstallation, moengage

We have a requirement where we have to send some business notifications (including whatsapp notification ) to the users existing in our data base. Since the whatsapp notifications are costly and there is a product requirement that we should send the whatsapp notification to the users who have app installed in their mobile. no need to send the users who have unisntalled the app.

What are the ways to find it out.

following solution i have alread read.

Using FCM from server side on can get to know whether app has installed or not based on the response they get of the sent notification.

We have a mobile web /PWA which is a exact copy of our android app. is there any way we can utilize it to find out the solution ?

Comment: You can make a record of user uninstalling your app. try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820327/android-uninstall-notification, and this  https://clevertap.com/blog/track-app-uninstalls-effectively/

Comment: You could use a custom install button to know when your app is installed. But as @Francesco mentions below, I don't THINK you can get a notification when a user uninstalls your app.

Comment: You may want to consider limiting messages to "active" users who have used the INSTALLED app in the last XX days. The hard part for you is selling that option to the people who give you the business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can append a query param to the start_url property in your web manifest:

```
"start_url": "/?utm_source=a2hs"
```

This way you can have a confirmation from the PWA users that the application (PWA I mean here) is installed. However this will help you only partially, since you cannot have any feedback if the users remove the PWA from their device.