# I want a way to accurately track user token removals & app uninstalls for my app in Android (GCM) and Apple (APNS)

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, push

I'm looking to accurately track users who decide they no longer want receive push notifications from my app OR users who delete the app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/BinaryProviderAPI.html

From Apple documentation here there are some push error codes but none seem to fit clearly with user token removal. A

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#table9

From the Google docs this following error code seems to be close to what I want.

> #### Error
>
> Unregistered Device
>
> #### HTTP Code
>
> 200 + error:NotRegistered:
>
> #### Recommended Action
>
> An existing registration token may cease to be valid in a number of scenarios, including:
>
> - If the client app unregisters with GCM.
> - If the client app is automatically unregistered, which can happen if
>     the user uninstalls the application. For example, on iOS, if the APNS
>     Feedback Service reported the APNS token as invalid.
> - If the registration token expires (for example, Google might decide
>     to refresh registration tokens, or the APNS token has expired for iOS
>     devices).
> - If the client app is updated but the new version is not configured to
>     receive messages.
>
> For all these cases, remove this registration token from the app server and stop using it to send messages.

It seems here there is no way to differentiate between app uninstalls / token removals & token expiration

I already am sure uninstalls can't be track with Apple.

Comment: Check this [thread](https://hackfindings.wordpress.com/2014/03/06/android-how-to-find-if-a-user-has-uninstalled-the-application/) on how to find if a user has uninstalled the application in Android. They provided here a scenario of what happens when you send a push to a device where your application has been uninstalled. From this scenario, your server gets `“NotRegistered”` error message, then the app has been uninstalled on the user’s device. So all you need to do is, send a silent push to your application, to check if it exists on user’s device.

Comment: Also, check these SO question [6209730](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209730/is-it-possible-to-detect-android-app-uninstall) and [18692571](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-can-an-app-detect-that-its-going-to-be-uninstalled) if it can help you.

Comment: So uninstalls don't seems to be difficult but the token removal problem seems a bit trickier