# how to implement un-installation listener for android app

Tags: android

I want to ask for password if someone attempts to uninstall my app. So is there any un-installation listener that I should implement? If not then how can I do this? Please help.

Comment: i think there is no such thing, take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6209769/5993410)

Answer (score 0):

For manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" /> 
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

By Activity

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL);
intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");
registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);
```

Comment: how to implement this? where is un-installation action action detected?

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />