# How do I get room database to persist through app reinstall?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-backup-service

I am trying to get my room database to persist through reinstall and on using a new phone. I am currently using key-value backups, with this simple code:

```
class AppBackupAgentHelper: BackupAgentHelper() {
override fun onCreate() {
    addHelper("MyDatabase",
        DatabaseBackupAgentHelper(
            this,
            "MyDatabase"
        )
    )
}

class DatabaseBackupAgentHelper(context: Context, dbName:String): FileBackupHelper(context,context.getDatabasePath(dbName).absolutePath)
```

My manifest has fullBackupContent = true and allowBackup =true and         android:backupAgent="com.example.myapplication3.BackupClasses.AppBackupAgentHelper"

In the app I am calling datachanged at certain points when saving app data. I am then using adb to make the backup manager run, having both tested adb shell bmgr backupnow , and adb bmgr run. Doing adb bmgr run gives me blank, but calls the onBackup methods in my app. Doing backupnow  gives me:

Running incremental backup for 1 requested packages.
Package @pm@ with result: Success
Package com.example.myapplication3 with result: Success
Backup finished with result: Success

It does not restore when I reinstall the app, nor does it restore when I use the token and package name and force a restore in adb, instead it gives me:

```
/adb shell bmgr restore current token package name
Scheduling restore: Google Pixel 2
restoreStarting: 0 packages
restoreFinished: 0
done
```

I feel like the error must be obvious in the restoreStarting: 0 packages, but I can't find anything online that hints at what would fix this or where I'm going wrong in my code.

The database is also not being restored when I try putting the app on another phone.

Let me know if you need more information,

Thanks for the help

EDIT:

I managed to get it to display restoreStarting 1 restoreFinishing 0. Logs are showing

```
2021-01-07 15:20:23.375 1393-3162/? D/BackupManagerService: initiateOneRestore packageName=@pm@
2021-01-07 15:20:23.411 1393-3162/? V/BackupManagerService: No more packages; finishing restore
2021-01-07 15:20:23.413 1393-3162/? I/BackupRestoreController: restoreFinished for 0
```

and on restore is not being called by my app

Edit 2:

It doesn't seem like the data is even being uploaded in the first place as I cannot find it on google drive. Here's the log of the backup manager running for my app.

```
2021-01-08 00:54:26.279 1393-15498/? D/BackupManagerService: [UserID:0] awaiting agent for ApplicationInfo{e23f643 com.example.myapplication3}
2021-01-08 00:54:26.293 1393-3923/? D/BackupManagerService: [UserID:0] agentConnected pkg=com.example.myapplication3 agent=android.os.BinderProxy@f2665f9
2021-01-08 00:54:26.293 1393-15498/? I/BackupManagerService: [UserID:0] got agent android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub$Proxy@e01793e
2021-01-08 00:54:26.294 1393-15498/? D/KeyValueBackupTask: Invoking agent on com.example.myapplication3
2021-01-08 00:54:26.299 32291-32458/? I/Backup: [CryptoEnableCheck] Should not encrypt backups: user not opted in.
2021-01-08 00:54:26.303 14524-14543/com.example.myapplication3 D/BackupHelperDispatcher: handling existing helper 'StoryDatabase' com.example.myapplication3.BackupClasses.DatabaseBackupAgentHelper@afc78a9
2021-01-08 00:54:26.320 1393-15498/? I/BackupRestoreController: Getting widget state for user: 0
2021-01-08 00:54:26.320 1393-15498/? V/BackupManagerConstants: getBackupFinishedNotificationReceivers(...) returns
```

Edit 3:

I've used pjv's answer from this post -
[Android backup/restore: how to backup an internal database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282936/android-backup-restore-how-to-backup-an-internal-database)

This definitely creates a backup of my database file to the google drive, but the file still doesn't get restored.

Edit 4:

Turns out this only works on the emulator... the data is still not being uploaded to google drive on my actual physical pixel 2. I also added synchronization to the onRestore and onBackup but this hasn't changed anything. Logging shows that the onRestore method is being called.

This post [Remove room database on app uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677497/remove-room-database-on-app-uninstall) proves that it is possible. I have moved to using auto backup (deleting backup agent) and it works! Will try and make the kv version work now. Still isn't working on physical device.

Edit 5:

Deleting my cloud backup and starting it again made my backups work on my physical device. Auto-backup allows the room database to persist through reinstall from android 23 onwards. I am still working on making key-value backups work for android version below 23.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Using a centralized database like **Firebase Realtime Database**.
2. Export your `Room` database data to a txt file, and after you reinstall the app on your new phone, import (read) the data from the txt file.

Comment: Is using android key-value backup not a viable option? I assumed that because you could do it for sql lite files it would work for a room database - I also thought there would be a way of using a key-value backup regardless, and that the issue lay mainly in my implementation of it.