# use ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to make an app when I remove it in setting meno,shows me a message that includ app's information . I know that I have to use BroadcastRiceiver for doing it, but I don't know how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648166/android-not-receiving-intent-action-package-removed-in-the-removed-package

Comment: I read it already,but I can't recognize how my app understand that the app is removing when I am removing it on setting menu...

Comment: in other word,I mean when I close my app by press back button on device,the app's action has closed,and then I go setting menu to removing it and when I want to remove the app ,the app hasen't existed that find out and then show a message...

Comment: there is only one way that your app is going to be uninstall is by this BroadcastReceiver by action ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED.even this receiver is fired after app is uninstall

Comment: even my app closed already?

Comment: The broadcast Intent that is sent informing of a package removal is broadcast **after your package is removed from the device**. Therefore, you will never ever be able to see this event.