# How to Call custom Method at time of uninstallation of application in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have prepared on application in Android, and I am in need to show one custom dialog at time of uninstallation of application.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-it-works-warning-that-app-is-going-to-be-uninstalled) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648166/android-not-receiving-intent-action-package-removed-in-the-removed-package) but not luck yet have tired to find out on goole too.

Is there any way that I can follow or any reference that can be helpful to me?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible, this question already exist [call function before uninstall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013823/perform-a-task-on-uninstall-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can't control when application is uninstalled. Sorry.